# Linearization of weighted average of decision variables

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have an optimization question. Consider a scenario where there are 2 storage bins with molten chocolate of different sweet levels. It can pull more from supply bins of any sweet level, just that the overall sweet level of each storage bin should not exceed a x%. Finally chocolate from these bins are processed to form chocolate bars. There are demand for different sweet level bars and the final sweet level of a chocolate bar is the weighted average of molten chocolate used from each of the storage bins. This blending equation results in a quadratic function of decision variables since the sweet level from storage bins is an weighted average by itself. Other than approximating this quadratic equation with McCormick envelopes and similar other techniques, Are there any tricks or quick heuristics  to estimate the sweet level of the final blend of chocolate bars? Any thoughts or ideas appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are solvers that can handle (non-convex) quadratic terms directly.

Comment: Gurobi couldn’t solve it within reasonable time. Do you have any other solver recommendations?

Comment: Modeling is a very important step. A problem can be modeled in different ways, and different formulations can make an enormous difference in the performance of the solver. Instead of looking at the solver, I would first make sure that my model is not just a bad formulation. Good, tight formulations can give a huge speed-up.